# django.contrib.sites table can not find in xadmin

Tags: django, admin

I relpaced admin with xadmin,however sites app in admin instead of xadmin
[image]

[image]

i want to know the reason,thanks!

Comment: have you added URL patterns? urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include(xadmin.site.urls)),
)

Comment: yes, and the table third app 'django-allauth'  also can be find in admin instead of xadmin。

Comment: remove the django admin from installed apps and urls and see

Comment: i've tried,but is show a Exception: "RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS."

Comment: have you added your own apps in installed apps?